# Laravel having space output issue in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Laravel code in Blade like this :

```
<span id="pk_dens" name="pk_dens" class="text-@if($productpages->pk_dens > 2.2 && $productpages->pk_dens < 3.3) success @else danger @endif">
{{$productpages->pk_dens}}%
</span>
```

So in `class="text-@if($productpages->pk_dens > 2.2 && $productpages->pk_dens < 3.3) success @else danger @endif"`

it will add space in class like `text- danger` and `text- success` so class not apply

so how can I avoid that spce in if else condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ternary operator

```
<span id="pk_dens" name="pk_dens" class="text-{{ ($productpages->pk_dens > 2.2 && $productpages->pk_dens < 3.3) ? 'success' : 'danger' }}">
    {{$productpages->pk_dens}}%
</span>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: this have issue `syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string "success", expecting ")"`

Comment: it works with : `{{ ($productpages->pk_dens > 2.2 && $productpages->pk_dens < 3.3) ? 'success' : 'danger' }} so need to add `?`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add question mark there. Please mark this thread as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing here is `?` in ternary syntax and to remove space just remove all white spaces from the `span` tag and make it in just one line.

```
<span id="pk_dens" name="pk_dens" class="text-{{ ($productpages->pk_dens > 2.2 && $productpages->pk_dens < 3.3) ? 'success' : 'danger' }}">{{$productpages->pk_dens}}%</span>
```